# Getting text from EditText without using XML id

Tags: android

I am programmatically creating an EditText field whose input value I need to read after. But when I try to read the text inside my OnClickListener, it says that textNewProdPrice is accessed within inner class and should be declared final. How do I get around this? This is what I have so far:

```
EditText textNewProdPrice = new EditText(this);
        textNewProdPrice.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        textNewProdPrice.setHint("New Value");
        textNewProdPrice.setTextSize(25);
        textNewProdPrice.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

        Button buttonPriceChange = new Button (this);
        buttonPriceChange.setClickable(true);
        buttonPriceChange.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonmain);
        buttonPriceChange.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        buttonPriceChange.setText("Change");
        buttonPriceChange.setTextSize(25);

        prodDetails.addView(textNewProdPrice);
        prodDetails.addView(buttonPriceChange);

buttonPriceChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String newProductPrice = textNewProdPrice.getText().toString();
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTS_PRICE, newProductPrice);
                dataBase.update(TABLE_NAME_PRODUCTS, values, "_id='" + currentProductID + "'");
                Intent intent = new Intent(products_details.this, products_details.class);
                intent.putExtra("currentProduct", currentProductID);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: use `setId()` method

Comment: Or just make it final! :O

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal As I understand this id is not XML so you can't used like this 'findViewById(R.id.entry)'

Comment: @Pavlos How do I make it final inside the onClick?

Comment: You make it final outside your onClick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `EditText` `final`

```
final EditText textNewProdPrice = new EditText(this);
```

or if you wish to refer it out of the block the use `setId()`

Documentation [setId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int)):

> Sets the identifier for this view. The identifier does not have to be unique in this view's hierarchy. The identifier should be a positive number.

```
EditText textNewProdPrice = new EditText(this);
textNewProdPrice.setId(1001); //Your any random id
```

Comment: Edit: it actually made sense to make it final inside onCreate, I just mixed the scopes. Thanks for the answer, will accept as soon as I can.

Making it final inside onCreate gives me no value to read on text, while inside the onClick it gives me error at this saying EditText cannot be applied to android.view.View.OnClickListener

Answer (score 1):

Just declare your EditText final, as suggested:

```
final EditText textNewProdPrice = new EditText(this);
```

Doing an ID lookup for the EditText would be a waste since you already have a reference to it.